# Touching the chart shows some dashed selection rectangle

Tags: java, android, teechart

I have a `TChart`. If I touch the screen a dashed selection rectangle is shown. I know I can change this to zooming or panning. How do I disable it altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashed rectangle is actually the Zooming rectangle for the InChart ZoomStyle. Draw the rectangle from TopLeft to BottomRight to zoom, and from BottomRight to TopLeft to unzoom.

Please, take a look at the "Tutorial 8 - Zoom and Scroll", the "How to Zoom and Scroll using the touch screen" section explains all this. The tutoatials are shipped with the installation.

Note there was a bug recently fixed affecting the FullChart ZoomStyle. It should be corrected with the next maintenance release.